# Firefox: HTML keyUp event has no event data

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, dom-events, onkeyup

The `onKeyUp` event is working in IE(7) and not in Firefox(4.0.1).

I have a textfield with attribute `onclick="eventName();"`
in the Javascript function `eventName(evt)`. I do not have an event data, the event data is not sent by Firefox. In IE on the other hand `window.event` IS filled so here it works...

Both IE and Firefox reach the function just fine. Only problem is that I need the event data there.
Can anyone direct me towards a solution for this annoying problem?

**Example page:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function upperCase(evt) { 
            if (evt) {
                var target = evt.target;
                target.value = target.value.toUpperCase();
            } else if (window.event) {
                var target = window.event.srcElement;
                target.value = target.value.toUpperCase();
            } else alert('No event information');
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <span>Enter your name: </span>
    <input type="text" id="fname" onkeyup="upperCase()" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

IE handles events with a global. Everything else the event passed as the first argument to the function.

```
onkeyup="upperCase()"
```

You don't do anything with it in there. I'm not even sure you can — I haven't touched an intrinsic event attribute for anything but the most trivial toy in years.

Given

```
document.getElementById('fname').keyup = upperCase;
```

(or, better, using attachEvent / addEvent, the `evt` variable will be populated.)

Answer (score 1):

To make this work in all browsers, pass the `event` to the function you're calling:

```
<input type="text" id="fname" onkeyup="upperCase(event)">
```

```js
function upperCase(evt) { 
  if (evt) {
    var target = evt.target;
    target.value = target.value.toUpperCase();
  } else if (window.event) {
    var target = window.event.srcElement;
    target.value = target.value.toUpperCase();
  } else alert('No event information');
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="fname" onkeyup="upperCase(event)">
```

In some browsers such as IE, this works because `event` resolves to `window.event`, which always refers to the current event being handled. In other browsers (such as Firefox), this works because `event` is a variable that's in scope for the event handler. You can imagine the contents of the `onkeyup` attribute as being the body of a function that looks like

```
function(event) {
    // Attribute value here
}
```

Comment: @Warface: Works fine for me in Firefox on OS X. There no reason why it shouldn't.

Comment: Dunno why... but window.event isn't recognized on my side. Had to do a `getElementsById().value` to get the value of the input... weird

Comment: @Warface: There's no `window.event` in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to actually pass the event as parameter, should be:

```
<input type="text" id="fname" onkeyup="upperCase(event)" />
```